# Using value of int in switch pattern matching return

Tags: c#, switch-statement, pattern-matching, c#-10.0

Seems to be something very simple I'm missing, but can't find any example of how to handle such case. I need to construct a switch statement like this (pseudocode):

```
a+b switch
{
   var sum: >0 => sum
};
```

I have a strong feeling that it should be possible for value types without using when, but I can't find syntax for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a ReSharper answer that for me eventually :)

So the syntax for it is:

```
a+b switch
{
   var sum and >0 => sum
};
```

It wasn't that obvious, hope it'll help someone

Answer (score 0):

```
a + b switch
{
   > 0 => returnValue;
   _ => catchAll;
}
```

Comment: return value should be a+b without re-evaluating it, that's the main problem

Comment: If your intent is to declare the evaluated variable within the switch expression then you're going to have to use `when`.

Comment: I believe there should be a way to achieve this without using when